# WiFi switching to 5G and ignoring BSSID and freq_list

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

I have a TP-Link router with 2.4G and 5G bands with the same SSID ("Smart connect", as they call it here).
My raspberry PI 4B is far from the router, and continually loses connection while on 5G, so I wanted to force it to connect to 2.4G.

For that, I tried:

- Setting the BSSID of the 2.4G in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (And the encoded psk)
- Setting `freq_list=2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472`

But none worked, it always connects to 5G.

This is the final conf:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=ES

network={
        id_str="home_2_4"
        bssid=<MY-2.4-BSSID>
        psk=my-hex-psk
        freq_list=2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
}
```

Trying to see the logs with `sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, I see it's continually switching between 2.4G and 5G, or looks like it:

```
$ sudo wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID ''
RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not associated
wlan0: Associated with <MY-2.4-BSSID>
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to <MY-2.4-BSSID> completed [id=0 id_str=home_2_4]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
wlan0: Associated with <MY-5G-BSSID>
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to <MY-5G-BSSID> completed [id=0 id_str=home_2_4]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=<MY-5G-BSSID> reason=2
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=ES
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID ''
RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not associated
wlan0: Associated with <MY-2.4-BSSID>
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to <MY-2.4-BSSID> completed [id=0 id_str=home_2_4]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=DE
wlan0: Associated with <MY-5G-BSSID>
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to <MY-5G-BSSID> completed [id=0 id_str=home_2_4]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=<MY-5G-BSSID> reason=2
```

Any idea of any way to force it to stay connected to 2.4G? I have to keep the router with the same SSID in both networks, and the raspi doesn't connect to 2.4G when the 5G connection is weak

About the "ES-DE" country, the router has DE, and I've set ES. But switching to DE doesn't change anything either